# Can I make a server on Minecraft edu? And if I can’t, can I join one?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

I want to play Minecraft with my friend in peace, but I don’t know how to on Education Edition **without** needing a join code. So I want to know if I can make a server in Minecraft Education Edition so we can play on it **whenever we want**. It would be so nice to have a place where we can build and show off said build to my friends without constantly asking  your friend the code so he/she can play it (and if another friend happens to be online, they can see the build) and come back to it by just joining the server!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to create or join a server in Minecraft Education Edition.